# Calculate number of active employees per month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following employee data in a table called **StaffDetailsTbl** on a sheet called Staff Details:

[image: Employee List]

I have another sheet with the following monthly sequence:

[image]

In B4 I have the following code to calculate the numbers of active monthly staff:

```
=LET(set, StaffDetailsTbl, starts, INDEX(set,,5), ends, INDEX(set,,6), SOMs, $B$1#,
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
  SUMPRODUCT((starts <= EOM) * (ends >= SOM))
 )))
)
```

However, as seen in the image above, it's giving incorrect numbers. This is because it doesn't account for the **Employment End Date** being empty, so only counts Dave. Is there a way I can modify this formula to include the employee in the count after their Employment Start Date if there's no Employment End Date?

The data used for the **StaffDetailsTbl** is:

| Employee | Employment Start Date | Employment End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 01/11/2019 |  |
| Dave | 01/11/2019 | 20/03/2020 |
| Wesley | 01/12/2019 |  |
| Peter | 01/12/2019 |  |
| Jack | 01/12/2019 |  |
| Richard | 01/12/2019 |  |
| Rodney | 01/12/2019 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when the employment end date is left blank, the headcount shall be continued for that person indefinitely.

Without trying to make it elegant, try the following adjustment:

```
=LET(set, StaffDetailsTbl, starts, INDEX(set,,5), ends, INDEX(set,,6), SOMs, $B$1#,
 BYCOL(SOMs, LAMBDA(SOM, LET(EOM, EOMONTH(SOM,0),
  SUMPRODUCT((starts <= EOM) * ((ends >= SOM) + ISBLANK(ends)))
 )))
)
```

So instead of only multiplying with `(ends >= SOM)`, you multiply with `((ends >= SOM) + ISBLANK(ends))` which is either 1 or 0 and shouldn't be able to be 2, because when `(ends >= SOM)` is TRUE, it cannot be blank so the second statement `ISBLANK(ends)` will then be FALSE, and vice versa.

Note: in case the end dates are actually not truly blank but just an empty string (because of a formula), then instead of `ISBLANK(ends)` use `LEN(ends)=0`.