# How to detect whether a month is present within two dates in excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis

I am trying to figure out how to find all active consultants within a certain month (in this case june) I have the start and end date for each consultant. I want to write a formula that will return 1 or 0 in the IsInJune column depending on whether june is present within the start and end date range. Also if this is not possible in excel, could PowerBI/powerquery/DAX be used for this?

[image]

I could not think of any formulae to use for this. I am expecting to return 1 or 0 based on if june is present within that range.

Comment: You should show what output you expect. Its is not clear if it needs to be full month in given period or 1 day is enough? This year or ant year?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74801156/4961700 ?

Comment: June of which year? Any year? Starting year? Ending year?

Comment: june of the starting year, and even 1 day is enough. I expect a 1 or 0 for output, or true or false. 1 being that june is in the range.

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, this would see if any period between start and end (of any year) is in June

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"start date", type date}, {"end date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "IsInJune?", each List.Contains(List.Transform({Number.From([start date])..Number.From([end date])}, each Date.Month(Date.From(_))),6))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

In powerquery, this would see if any period between start and lesser of (end  if year, end date) is in June

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"start date", type date}, {"end date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "IsInJune?", each List.Contains(List.Transform({Number.From([start date])..List.Min({Number.From(#date(Date.Year([start date]),12,31)),Number.From([end date])})}, each Date.Month(Date.From(_))),6))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, assuming start date is in column A starting A2:

`=IF(MONTH(A2)<=6,IF(B2-DATE(YEAR(A2),6,30)>-30,1,0),0)`

Paste this in C2 and fill down as required

Comment: Thank you! this worked! I don't understand it, would you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: @AdamChabaane 2 nested conditions, 1 - if starting date is PAST June then there's nothing else to check, it's 0 immediately. 2 - assuming starting date is June or earlier (since cond 1), the only thing to check is end date is June 1 or later same year. Between June 1 and 30 is 29 days, anything later will (by plain logic) include at least 1 day of June, hence >-30. If you like the answer - please consider upvoting / accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hey, so I tried the same formula for february but it won't work. =IF(MONTH([@[Start Date]])<=2,IF([@[End Date]]-DATE(YEAR([@[Start Date]]),2,28)>-28,1,0),0)

Comment: @AdamChabaane elaborate more please + provide new dataset

Comment: Okay so i tried a different formula with similar logic:

Comment: =IF(AND(MONTH(A2)<=MONTH(DATE(YEAR(A2),$B$4,1)),MONTH(B2)>=MONTH(DATE(YEAR(B2),$B$4,1))),1,0) . Now i have the start dates set as 6/9/2023 and end date is 9/1/2024. B4 represents the month im testing for (may in this case) A2 is the cell with the start date and B2 is the cell with the end date (sorry i could not post a picture in the comment). But basically the issue im running into is that the formula is not taking the next year into account: if i test for may which is in the range, i get false. but when i test for july it returns true. I hope this clarifies it, if not let me know!